# The direct image of an ideal need not be an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> I need an example of a ring homomorphism such that the image of an ideal needs not to be an ideal.

I found that the image is an ideal if the mapping is onto, so all we need to find a mapping that is not onto.

Comment: To find a mapping which isn't onto, one idea is to find a ring strictly contained in another ring, and consider the inclusion map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Try $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ with $f(n) = n$. It should be clear that this is a ring homomorphism. Then try looking at an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, say, $2\mathbb{Z}$ and see if this is indeed an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: In general, any inclusion map from a domain (which is not a field) into its field of fractions (or any nontrivial localisation) yields an example.

Comment: oh thank u . I guess it is a perfect solution :)